# How to download any file from server on specific location in android 10?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-10.0

My code for download file from server is working fine on API level 28 and below but it is not working on API level 29.

```
private fun downloadV(url: String) {
    val fileName = System.currentTimeMillis().toString() + ".mp4"
    val downloaduri = Uri.parse(url)
    val request = DownloadManager.Request(downloaduri)
    request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI or DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
    request.setAllowedOverRoaming(false)
    request.setTitle(fileName)
    request.setDescription(fileName)
    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/XYZ", fileName)
    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner()
    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
    downloadManager?.enqueue(request)
}
```

Comment: You forgot to tell why your code is not suitable for SDK 30. Please tell exception and message. Look in the Logcat.

Comment: `"XYZ"` is no public dir so it is not usable to set the destination in Android 10 and 11. But you could tell the downloadmanager to download to Download/XYZ or for instance Pictures/XYZ. The XYZ folder will be created by the manager.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to Manifest in Application tag

```
requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this document once
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#grant-access-directory

or try to grant runtime permission for storage

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
    }

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
    }
```

Comment: already permissions are granted before download start

Comment: android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" add this to manifst in application tag